# C++ conditional construction of template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
struct A {};

template<typename T, typename U> struct B : public A {};

std::unique_ptr<A> chooseB(int i, int j)
{
  // return B<T, U> where T and U vary with i and j (0 = int, 1 = double etc.) 
}
```

`i` and `j` are not known at compile time. Potentially the list of types could be long enough that just forming a big conditional that enumerates all possible pairs of `i` and `j` could be painful.

Is there are nice way to write the `chooseB` function? I might potentially want to generalize this to more than two template parameters.

Comment: Are the parameters of `chooseB` known at compile time?

Comment: No. For example, I might want to construct a B based on parsed information. (I have edited the question to make this clear).

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which C++ does not support. Although there might be workarounds as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Time for some abuse.

We're going to write a function that will figure out which type corresponds to a given index. But we can't return that type - the return type must be known at compile-time. So instead we'll forward that along to a function that we provide. I'll start with the end-result:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> chooseB(int i, int j)
{
    using choices = typelist<int, double>;

    return pick_elem<std::unique_ptr<A>>(i, choices{}, 
        [=](auto tag1){
            return pick_elem<std::unique_ptr<A>>(j, choices{}, 
                [=](auto tag2) {
                    using T1 = typename decltype(tag1)::type;
                    using T2 = typename decltype(tag2)::type;

                    return std::make_unique<B<T1, T2>>();
                });
            });
}
```

`pick_elem` takes three arguments: the index, the list of choices, and the function to forward along with. So we call it with the first index and call a lambda -- which in turns calls it with the second index and calls another lambda -- which finally makes our `B`.

You have to explicitly provide the return type to `pick_elem<>` because it needs to halt recursion somehow and that end-step will need to know what to return. So we start with some convenient metaprogramming helpers:

```
template <class... > struct typelist {};
template <class T> struct tag { using type = T; };
```

And then `pick_elem` is:

```
template <class R, class F>
R pick_elem(int , typelist<>, F )
{
    throw std::runtime_error("wtf");
}


template <class R, class T, class... Ts, class F>
R pick_elem(int i, typelist<T, Ts...>, F f)
{
    if (i == 0) {
        return f(tag<T>{});
    }
    else {
        return pick_elem<R>(i-1, typelist<Ts...>{}, f);
    }
}
```

---

This can be generalized to arbitrarily many types by making `chooseB` variadic itself. In a way, this is actually cleaner than what I had before. `chooseB()` now additionally takes some non-deducible arguments that are the types we've figured out so far:

```
template <class... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<A> chooseB()
{
    return std::make_unique<B<Ts...>>();
}

template <class... Ts, class Idx, class... Rest>
std::unique_ptr<A> chooseB(Idx i, Rest... rest)
{
    using choices = typelist<int, double>;

    return pick_elem<std::unique_ptr<A>>(i, choices{},
        [=](auto tag){
            return chooseB<Ts..., typename decltype(tag)::type>(rest...);
        });
}
```

You can add some safety around this by asserting that the number of arguments is correct.

Comment: Wow, that was quick and impressive. I expected the answer would be something like this (variadic templates with recursion and tricks). I'm still working through it, but as I'm using C++11, not 14, I can't have generic lambdas so will need to do something slightly different with the lambda in chooseB.

Answer (score 1):

My pragmatic solution inspired by 0x499602D2 above. This will actually probably work for OK for the problem at hand - but I *was* interested in more general answers that don't rely on specific enumeration of all possibilities.

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void printTypes() = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct B : public A 
{
    virtual void printTypes() override
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ", " << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::function<std::unique_ptr<A> ()>> m = 
        {
            {{0, 0}, [](){return std::unique_ptr<A>(new B<int, int>);}},
            {{0, 1}, [](){return std::unique_ptr<A>(new B<int, double>);}},
            {{1, 0}, [](){return std::unique_ptr<A>(new B<double, int>);}},
            {{1, 1}, [](){return std::unique_ptr<A>(new B<double, double>);}}
        };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            auto a = m[std::make_pair(i, j)]();
            a->printTypes();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map both numbers to instantiations of the base class:

```c++
#define FWD(x) std::forward<decltype(x)>((x))
auto p=[](auto&&l,auto&&r){return std::make_pair(FWD(l),FWD(r));};

std::unique_ptr<A> chooseB(int i, int j) {
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>,std::unique_ptr<A>> m;
    m.emplace(p(p(0,0),std::make_unique<B<int,int>>()));
    m.emplace(p(p(0,1),std::make_unique<B<int,double>>()));
    m.emplace(p(p(1,0),std::make_unique<B<double,int>>()));
    m.emplace(p(p(1,1),std::make_unique<B<double,double>>()));
    /* and so on for different (i,j) */
    return std::move(m[p(i,j)]);
}
```

If you want to generalize this for more than two parameters, then have the function take a parameter pack (`Args&&...`) possibly SFINAE-ified to all integers, and use a `std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args...>>` instead of a pair.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did want to look for a generic solution that doesn't explicitly consider all the possible combinations of `i` and `j` one by one, but on the other hand it may turn out that something along the lines you suggest may end up being the most pragmatic solution for what I want to do.

Comment: My pragmatic solution inspired by your one is below. This will actually probably work for OK for the problem at hand - but I *was* interested in more general answers that don't rely on specific enumeration of all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Make a jump table and dispatch.

```
template<size_t I, class... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<A> do_make() {
    using T = std::tuple_element_t<I / sizeof...(Ts), std::tuple<Ts...>>;
    using U = std::tuple_element_t<I % sizeof...(Ts), std::tuple<Ts...>>;
    return std::make_unique<B<T,U>>();
}
template<class... Ts, size_t...Is>
std::unique_ptr<A> make(size_t i, size_t j, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using fptr_t = std::unique_ptr<A> (*)();
    static constexpr fptr_t table[] = { do_make<Is, Ts...> ...};
    return table[ i * sizeof...(Ts) + j]();
}

template<class... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<A> make(size_t i, size_t j) {
    return make<Ts...>(i, j, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) * sizeof...(Ts)>());
}
```